# C++ void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, hdf5

I am using an HDF5 library to read data from an HDF5 file in c++ and the call I am having problems with is the following:

```
status = H5Dread(
    hdf5_dataset,
    hdf5_datatype,
    hdf5_dataspace_in_memory,
    hdf5_dataspace_in_file,
    H5P_DEFAULT,
    buf
);
```

The last argument is supposed to be a void pointer, and I have a vector of floats that I want to be allocated, however when I try to pass the vector g++ gives me the following error:

> error: cannot convert `‘std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >’` to `‘void*’` for      argument `‘6’` to `‘herr_t H5Dread(hid_t, hid_t, hid_t, hid_t, hid_t, void*)’`

Is there any way that I can write directly to the vector without having to allocate the memory twice?

Comment: "...without having to allocate the memory twice" - what is that supposed to mean? I don't see you allocating any memory even once. Where did "twice" come from?

Comment: @AndreyT: The vector allocates memory once. He's trying to avoid having to allocate a new block and copy his data there; he wants to re-use the existing block despite now having not a `float*`, but a `void*`, to iterate it.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Well,  again, in order to properly use a vector in the above context, one has to do two things: pre-allocate internal vector memory and pass it to the function properly. Which is why I want to see how the memory is allocated as well. Because without it the whole thing won't work (even if you get rid of the above error).

Comment: @AndreyT: If he's worried about having to allocate twice, odds are he's already allocating once.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: No, odds are that the OP is not bothering about allocation at all, expecting that the vector somehow will do everything automatically. The OP's first comment after the accepted answer is a good indication of that the OP does not have a good idea about memory management in this case. (The author of the answer also ignored the issue at first. I'd call the current code sample there misleading.)

Comment: @AndreyT: "not bothering about allocation at all" according to... what? You don't see where `buf` comes from.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: No, I don't see it. That's why I'm worried.

Comment: @AndreyT: Oh well, you don't have to worry any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `std::vector` guarantees the data is stored in contiguous memory, you can convert a vector to a pointer like so:

```
std::vector<float> myFloats;
void *ptr = static_cast<void*>(&myFloats[0]); // or &myFloats.front()
```

Edit: if you are writing to it without calling `push_back`, make sure you `resize` enough space first!

Comment: Thanks, thats just what I needed. And fast too!
Once I'm done, I can just dereference and delete the pointer right?

Comment: No, the memory is owned by the `std::vector`, it will handle deletion once it is destroyed itself (either goes out of scope or is deleted if it was new'd)

Comment: @Node: Note that either of these options has undefined behavior if the vector is empty. And for getting results from a C API, you need `resize` not `reserve`.

Comment: @Billy good point, thats what I was thinking, just not what I typed :) - edited.

Comment: Why did you add the cast?  It is wholly unnecessary.

Comment: @James: Clarity? I'd probably use it, in hindsight. There are lots of "unnecessary" things that are regardless a good idea to do.

Comment: @James: as Tomalak said, just for clarity.

Comment: @Tomalak @Node:  The conversion from `T*` to `void*` where `T` is an object type is implicit.  Why would you use a cast where the conversion that does what you want is implicit?  It isn't clearer at all; it just adds noise and forces you to spend more time reading the line of code to make sure it really does something safe.

Comment: @James: On the one hand, yes. On the other, it means you _don't_ have to spend more time reading the line of code wondering whether you really meant for a conversion to take place there.

Answer (score 4):

Given a `std::vector<float>`, you can obtain a pointer to the contiguous buffer of `float`s thus:

```
std::vector<float> v;
fillMyVectorSomehow(v);

float* buffer = &v[0]; // <---
```

You could cast this to `void*` and pass it through.

Comment: @Billy: But I _wouldn't_ write out an explicit cast. `void* vp = buffer;`

Comment: @Billy: Well, ok, maybe I would.