# Reading hdf5 into c++ with memory problems

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, hdf5

I am rewriting a code I had developed in python into c++ mainly for an improvement in speed; while also hoping to gain more experience in this language.  I also plan on using openMP to parallelize this code onto 48 cores which share 204GB of memory.

The program I am writing is simple, I import an hdf5 file which is 3D : 
A[T][X][E], where T is associated to each timestep from a simulation, X represents where the field is measured, and E(0:2) represents the electric field in x,y,z.
Each element in A is a double, and the bin sizes span: A[15000][80][3].

The first hiccup I have run into is inputting this 'large' h5 file into an array and would like a professional opinion before I continue.  My first attempt:

```
...
#define RANK  3
#define DIM1  15001
#define DIM2  80
#define DIM3  3

using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
//  Define HDF5 variables for opening file. 
hid_t   file1, dataset1;
double bufnew[DIM1][DIM2][DIM3];
herr_t ret;
uint  i, j, k;

file1 = H5Fopen (FILE1, H5F_ACC_RDWR, H5P_DEFAULT);
dataset1 = H5Dopen (file1, "EFieldOnLine", H5P_DEFAULT);
ret = H5Dread (dataset1, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL,
                H5P_DEFAULT, bufnew);

cout << "Let's try dumping 0->100 elements" << endl;
for(i=1; i < 100; i++) cout << bufnew[i][20][2] << endl;
...
```

which leads to a segmentation fault from array declaration.  My next move was to use either a 3D array (new), or a 3D vector.  However, I have seen much debate against these methods, and more importantly, I only need ONE component of the E, i.e. I would like to reshape A[T][X][E] -> B[T][X] for say, the x-component of E.

Sorry for the lengthy post, but I wanted to be as clear as possible and would like to emphasize again that I am interested in learning how to write the fastest, and most efficient code.
I appreciate all of your suggestions, time and wisdom.

Comment: Most likely `bufnew` is too large for the stack you probably need to dynamically allocate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining an array as a local variable means allocating it on stack. The stack is usually limited with several megabytes, and stack overflow surely leads to a segfault. Large data structures should be allocated at heap dynamically (using `new` operator) or statically (when defined as global variables).

I wouldn't advise to make a vector of vectors of vectors for such dimensions.

Instead, creating a one-dimensional array to store all values

```
double *bufnew = new double[DIM1*DIM2*DIM3];
```

and accessing it with the following formula to calculate linear position of a given 3D item

```
bufnew[(T*DIM2+X)*DIM3+E] = ... ; // bufnew[T][X][E]
```

should work ok.

Comment: The only problem I see with this, is that the function: 
    H5Dread (dataset1, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, bufnew);
assigns bufnew the shape of dataset1 with no flexibility.  Would it then be best to temporarily create a 3D new array, bufnew0; and then delete it after creating a 1D array, bufnew1 with your suggested formula? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the HD5read seems to always read the whole dataset into memory. Whether it would be better or not to reshape the array in memory - that depends on what you want to achieve and how the array is used. If the dimensions are 15000*80*3, then it's 3 600 000 of doubles which is approx. 28 MB of RAM (I assume that a double takes 8 bytes). Is it critical to save 18 MB via reshaping the array, or would it be ok to go with 28 MB? Maybe it's not worth reshaping. But if the 1D-array is intensively used then it's definitely better to reshape to make the array more cache-friendly.

Comment: It seems that H5Dread does not like writing to a new 3D array; when I try to view a single element I get segmentation fault.  I checked using a very small array/h5 file, that a static array does indeed work.  Any thoughts?  I came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393178/c-void-pointer

Comment: If the segfault occurs when you try to VIEW an alement, it's probably not H5Dread that fails but the access code. Static arrays and "dynamic" arrays do not have any significant differences in the terms of passing as pointers. I suppose it's the wrong index when you view elements or the wrong size of the allocated memory block. How does the faulting code looks like?

Comment: I've rewritten the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110435/reading-hdf5-files-to-dynamic-arrays-in-c and provided an example which illustrates this problem.  Thanks for your help!