# How to store values from hdf5 into FloatArray?

Tags: c++, hdf5

i am a matlab Programmer. And i have some experimental data in HDF5 format.
I would like to transfer this data into an array for further processing.
It is a 3Dimensional Array ( 754 x 250 x 250 ) containing double values.

The data itself is > 5 GB
What is the best way to do this ? ( without getting problems with memory )

Comment: What library are you using to read HDF5?  Also, 754 x 250 x 250 x 8 / 1024 / 1024 is only 360 MB, so why do you say the data is > 5 GB?

Comment: maybe this has the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076540/reading-hdf5-into-c-with-memory-problems?rq=1

Comment: @JohnZwinck this is just a Toy example. And yeah, the data is about 300 MB. :) well read !

Comment: @tevlon84: so  are you using http://ftp.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/index.html or what?

Comment: @fritzone No, this doesn't help. In fact, he has the same Problem. As far as i can tell.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Hi Mark. I have no problem using this data in matlab, in fact, the data is created in matlab and saved as HDF5. I have some lagacy c++ code for processing these kind of data.

Comment: It might be easier, since you seem more confident with Matlab+HDF5 than with C+++HDF5, to write a Matlab function to export the needed data into a form which is easier for you to deal with than having to use the full-blown C++/HDF5 interface.  Something like a nice, simple binary file containing just the real values you want to process in C++ perhaps, with a header line if you like with the dimensions of the cube of data.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: with all due respect, I don't think that's a good idea at all.  Using HDF5 is not so hard that it warrants dumping the data to an ad-hoc binary format which will then be harder to debug and maintain for others.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I don't disagree with your review of my suggestion.  But I don't see anyone offering an answer yet.